# Getting number of CPUs on Mac OS X from C?

Tags: c, api, macos, parallel-processing

Is there a C API function that will give me the number of CPUs/cores on Mac OS X?  Ideally, it should be something that just works across all flavors of OS X.  (I really know nothing about Mac OS.  This is for a library I'm working on that needs to support OS X.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sysctlbyname()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html) with e.g. `machdep.cpu.core_count`. Do a `sysctl -a` from the command line to see what might be useful to you.